# Should fruit in secondary produce CO2?

Tags: beer, secondary-fermentation, fruit, belgian

I had a Belgian Dubbel in primary about two weeks, ending up with a gravity of 1.016. Then 3 days ago I racked onto 5.5 lbs of cherries, leaving the yeast cake behind.

I expected the residual yeast to cause additional fermentation and generate CO2, along with bubbling through airlock. I measured the gravity at 1.014, but that seems within the margin of error.

This is my first fruit beer: is this progressing as it should, or should I add more yeast to advance fermentation?

Comment: Did you prep the cherries? By freezing or cutting? If not, there may not be any sugar in the beer or cherry flavor.

Comment: Yes, the cherries were prepped by removing the pits and freezing them in ziplock bags. Then I boiled them (190 degrees) in the ziplock bags to sanitize. So they were reasonably broken down after that.

Comment: then I'm sure it did ferment the fruit. You probably just missed the activity.

Answer (score 3):

The fruit very likely has sugar, so it will cause fermentation to kick-off again when  added, thus producing CO2.  Obviously not with the same vigour as primary fermentation - although if you added *a lot* of fruit, maybe.  Is the yeast able to get into the fruit?  The skins are fairly tough for yeast, so will need to be broken somewhat.  I typically mush my fruit a little with a potato masher (or slice - depends on the type of fruit).

I wouldn't be too concerned about the airlock not bubbling - this is mostly an indication that it's not perfectly sealed somehow.  Or maybe it's going slowly, and you've not witnessed the odd bubble.

One other thing I would like to add - when I've added fruit to beers, sometimes it doesn't taste so good until it's been conditioning for a while.  For example: A friend made a raspberry stout, and it was OK after a month or so, but after 3 months it was very nice indeed.  So if at first the flavour is not pleasing, just wait.

Cherry dubbel sounds like a good mix BTW.

Comment: If it's in a bucket then I find the lids often don't seal well and thus CO2 escapes without creating bubbles in the airlock

Comment: It's also good to remember that the sugar in fruit won't be as easily available because it is locked inside the fruit, so fermentation will be slower due to this.

Comment: I used the extract version of this recipe: https://www.homebrewersassociation.org/homebrew-recipe/cherry-dubbel/

Comment: @Robert Zormeir: Sorry, I didn't get your comment. What do you mean by "locked  inside the fruit" ? :)